# tensorflow - top k values in vector to binary vector

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I had a vector with values `[0,4,1,2,8,7,0,2]`, how can I get a binary vector of the top k values (k = 3) `[0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]` in **tensorflow**?

Answer (score 1):

The TensorFlow's [`tf.math.top_k`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k) will find the values for you. But to obtain a binary mask, you need [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd).

This code must work for the task:

```
x = tf.convert_to_tensor([0,4,1,2,8,7,0,2])
_, indices = tf.math.top_k(x, k=3)
result = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(indices, 1), tf.ones_like(indices), tf.shape(x))
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=47, shape=(8,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int32)>
```

Please note, that before v1.13, the `top_k` operation is under `tf.nn.top_k`:

```
_, indices = tf.nn.top_k(x, k=3)
```